# Displaying Image on Same Page Using Drop Down Box

Tags: php, image, dropdown

I am using the current code to display an image depending on the selection from a dropdown box but I am using a go button. I want to display the image from just selecting from the dropdown box. Any help would be greatly appreciated

```
<form name="product" method="post" action="">
<table align="right" width="10%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
<tr>
<td>Category</td>
<td>
<select name="idnum">

<?php


$sql = "SELECT ID,idnum,title,brief FROM table where passw='tsmith';";
$result = mysql_query($sql);
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
?>

<option value="<?= $row['idnum']; ?>"><?= $row['title']; ?></option>


<?php } ?>
</select>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td><input name="go" type="submit" value="Go" /></td>
</tr>
</table>
   </form>
<div align="center">

 <ul class='display'>
 <?php
 $idnum = (int)$_POST['idnum'];
 $sql_search = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE idnum = $idnum";
 $search = mysql_query($sql_search);
 if (isset($_POST['go'])) {
 while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($search)) {
     $imagepath1= "p".$idnum."n1.jpg";
$path='/components/com/photos/'.$imagepath1;
$image1 =("<img src='$path' width='200' height = '221'/>");

echo $image1;
     ?>


<img src = "/components/com/photos/p.$row['idnum'].n.jpg">;
<li><a href="<?= $row['title']; ?>"><img src="<?= $row['title']; ?>" border="0"></a></li>
<?php
```

}

```
}

else {

}


?>
</div>
```

Comment: You'll need a pure JavaScript solution then. Google for the `change` handler on select boxes and you should be fine.

Comment: `Table` is reserved keyword in mysql it must be in bachtick http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/keywords.html

Answer (score 0):

As an example as to how you might do this, without reloading the page each time, the following might be useful. The javascript function is attached (inline) to the actual select element rather than a button and is invoked on the `onchange` event. The value of the selected element is used in the ajax function and is sent, via a `POST` request to the portion of the script that processes the request and does the database lookup to find the image. You will need to amend that portion of code to return the correct image... The response is handled by the ajax callback function.

Do however be aware that using `mysql_*` functions are now discouraged due to the risk of sql injection so perhaps, before getting to in-depth with things, you might wish to consider learning about mysqli or PDO where you can use prepared statements which help mitigate against this risk. Your original, and my code, embed the POST var in the sql which is BAD... this is just for example though '-)

```
<?php
    /*
        include whatever files needed & set session vars if required
    */
    if( $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST' ){


        $idnum=$_POST['idnum'];
        $sql="select * from `table` where `idnum`='$idnum';";
        /* execute the query and generate the response */


        exit("<img src='/components/com/photos/{$imagepath1}' />");
    }
?>
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Change image</title>
        <script>
            function changeimg(v){
                http=new XMLHttpRequest();
                http.onreadystatechange=function(){
                    if( http.readyState==4 && http.status==200 )cbchangeimg.call( this, http.response );
                };
                http.open('POST',document.location.href,true);
                http.setRequestHeader('Content-type','application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
                http.send('idnum='+v);
            }

            function cbchangeimg(r){
                /* process response: change the image */
                document.getElementById('myImg').src=r;
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <img id='myImg' src='/images/placeholder.jpg' />
        <select name='idnum' onchange='changeimg(this.value)'>
            <option value=1>One
            <option value=2>Two
        </select>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: What I am doing in my initial code is first querying the database to populate the values from the database of the items of a particular user. The second query is to then chose the item from the dropdown box take the associated id number of that item and format it to the image filename in the photo directory, for example.  idnum=235 image id would equal p.235n.jpg. In your example you are just using a predefined dropdown box. Could you elaborate more specifically as to what I am looking for. I truly appreciate all of your help...